# Can't insert new row in cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am not able to insert a new row in table and getting the error

> 2016-04-12 09:23:54 Error: [RuntimeException] Cannot insert row in
>   "table_name" table, it has no primary key. Request URL:

I am using ORM and my code given below

```
$entityTable = TableRegistry::get('TableName');
$entity = $entityTable->newEntity();
$entity->name = 'Test Name';
$entity->image = 'test.png';
$entity->type = 1;
if($entityTable->save($entity)) {
    $this->Flash->success('Added successfully.');
} else {
    $this->Flash->error('Error!.');
}
```

And my table is

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: add $this->primaryKey('id');   in src>>Model>>Table>>TableNamesTable... in your initialize method

Comment: Its working fine now . Thanks @ prats1411

Comment: aaah.. the answer got posted now, it was lost in one of the tabs.. glad it is working, please mark it as right :) thanks!

Comment: CakePHP is able to read the primary key from the schema though, so you might still want to inspect what's going wrong in your setup.

Comment: Yes you are right @ndm  . There is something wrong now its saving blank for field 'image' but i have test.png for $entity->image = 'test.png';

Comment: Found the real problem: Whenever you do any database changes then you need to Clear files under \app\tmp\cache\mode or set debug mode as 2

Comment: @AmitKumar your last comment should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `$this->primaryKey('id');`

in src>>Model>>Table>>TableNamesTable... 
in your initialize method